# Doing "if string a contains any letter in string b" with Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I've been programming with Python, but all the methods I can think of are stupidly long, and I feel like there must be a better way.

Is there a quick way (maybe 1 line or 2 lines?) to do:

```
if (stringA.containsAnyLetterIn(stringB)):
    do stuff
```

For example, I want

```
stringA = 'abcdefg'
stringB = 'hijklmn'
print stringA.containsAnyLetterIn(stringB)
```

to return `False`, and I want

```
stringA = 'dog'
stringB = 'abcdefg'
print stringA.containsAnyLetterIn(stringB)
```

to return `True` (since `d` and `g` are in stringB).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function and `in` operator, like this

```
any(char in stringB for char in stringA)
```

Demo:

```
>>> stringA, stringB = 'abcdefg', 'hijklmn'
>>> any(char in stringB for char in stringA)
False
>>> stringA, stringB = 'dog', 'abcdefg'
>>> any(char in stringB for char in stringA)
True
```

If you want an efficient solution, convert `stringA` to a set and then check if the set and `stringB` are [`disjoint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint) or not, like this

```
>>> stringA, stringB = 'abcdefg', 'hijklmn'
>>> not set(stringA).isdisjoint(stringB)
False
>>> stringA, stringB = 'dog', 'abcdefg'
>>> not set(stringA).isdisjoint(stringB)
True
```

Comment: I did find `any` and `in` operators while googling for this topic, but I didn't know I could combine them. Thanks.

Comment: @Tetsudou:  `any` and `in` are two different things.  `any` is a built-in function that returns `True` on the first element that it finds to be `True` in an iterable.  `in` is an operator that allows you to check for membership in an iterable.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `set` and & intersection operator here:

```
>>> bool(set('abcdefg') & set('hijklmn'))
>>> bool(set('abcdefg') & set('dog'))
```

Or the slightly more verbose but probably more performant

```
>>> bool(set('abcdefg').intersection('hijklmn'))
```

(faster because the second string is not converted to a set before).

This is especially good if you need to get all common characters:

```
>>> set('abcdefg') & set('dog')
set(['d', 'g'])
```

---

If you can make a regex character class of it, use:

```
>>> import re
>>> bool(re.search('[abcdefg]', 'hijklmn'))
False
>>> bool(re.search('[abcdefg]', 'dog'))
True
```

Now if it is an user input string, then making a character class of it might be a bit tricky.

Comment: This works, but since one is using regex, they now have two problems.

Comment: I was half-joking.  The language offers list comprehensions to do something like this; if one just wanted a simple solution, they'd both need to know what to do *and* express the regular expression required to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Convert strings to list, then check each character in the list using list comprehension.

```
stringA = 'abcdefg'
stringB = 'hijklmn'

print any([character in list(stringB) for character in list(stringA)])
```

Comment: Why do you feel the need to convert the strings to lists?  Both lists and strings are iterable.

Comment: @srekcahrai python treats strings as char arrays (lists) so you don't need to convert it

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the most elegant way would be to use a `set`:

```
>>> stringA = 'abcdefg'
>>> stringB = 'hijklmn'
>>> set(stringA).intersection(stringB)
set()
>>> stringA = 'dog'
>>> stringB = 'abcdefg'
>>> set(stringA).intersection(stringB)
{'d', 'g'}
```

with the additional benefit of telling you *which* characters can be found in both strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool(set(a) & set(b))
```